# Importing two utility classes with same name. Feature or useless?

Tags: java

For two utility classes with the same names, which contain only static methods, I proceeded as follows:

1. Simply imported the first
2. Created an instance of the second class.

Example:

```
package util1;

public class Utility {
  public static void method() {
    System.out.println("First Utility. static method");
  }
}
```

```
package util2;

public class Utility {
    public static void method() {
        System.out.println("Second Utility. static method");
    }
}
```

```
import util1.Utility;

public class Component {

    private static final util2.Utility anotherUtility = new util2.Utility();

    public static void usedByReflection() {
        Utility.method();
        anotherUtility.method();
    }
}
```

Now I don't need to write a full second util-class name for invoke its methods, but maybe I did not foresee something...?

P.S:
The methods of the class Component are called through a reflection by a certain BlackBox. All the multithread-safe features are in BlackBox.

**UPD:** I have found better trick:

```
import util1.Utility;

public class Component {

    private static final util2.Utility anotherUtility = null; // There are some changes

    public static void usedByReflection() {
        Utility.method();
        anotherUtility.method();
    }
}
```

Now I dont create new object, but is it possible to use it without any bugs?

Comment: This looks more like a naming issue. Then both methods do the same thing (hence the same name), then why are they in split into two different classes in two packages? And if they don't do the same thing, then why doesn't the name reflect that properly?

Comment: Why did you create an instance of the util2.Utility? Instead of `anotherUtility.method();` you could have simply used the full qualified name: `util2.Utility.method();`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS He doesn't want to write the FQN. It's part of his question.

Comment: full class name may be  very long like com.somebeautifulfolder.someanotherbeautifulfolder. (...) .lastfolder.BeautifulClass and then it will not be clearly to use full name. I use this trick for normal-view code, when write it, then I change tmp-simple name for full class name.

Comment: There are two project Account and Customer. My project need to use they like external libs. These classes was created by same template with package util, and class Utility. Let's say, that I need to create class Loan, then it needs Utility of both classes.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, this is confusing and could much more clearly be handled by something like:

```
public class CombinedUtilityComponent {

    public static void usedByReflection() {
        util1.Utility.method();
        util2.Utility.method();
    }
}
```

Or, better yet, in your code you can just fully qualify the class names and they become unique names without any confusing tricks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Or...fully qualify the class names"? that's what you did in your code example

Comment: full class name may be like com.somebeautifulfolder.someanotherbeautifulfolder. (...) .lastfolder.BeautifulClass and then it will not be clearly to use full name. I use this trick for normal-view code, when write it, then I refactor it.

Comment: @Oleg - Well, in my example I created a class to combine the methods. I was using "Or" as a conjunction to suggest an alternative: That instead of my example (i.e. the new class) the OP could "in your code just fully qualify the class names", thus not needing the new class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works. I wouldn't do it, though.

You're calling a `static` method as if it were an instance method. `anotherUtility.method()` has a useless reference to `anotherUtility`.

You also have an unnecessary instantiation of `util2.Utility`. This technique wouldn't work if the default constructor were disabled.

Comment: Pay attention to update of my question. It works without constructor)